# Align on the left

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid, alignment

i have this website http://steam-to-rent.ch/ and what i need is to align the entire content on the left **(same line as the Logo)**. I'm using bootstrap grid but in the homepage and here http://steam-to-rent.ch/uber.html i can't align on the left. This is the HTML code:

```
<section id="services" class="section text-center home">
                <div class="container">

                        <div class="row">

                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".6s">

                                <div class="service-content home">
                                    <h3 class="">Dampf wird überall gebraucht! </h3>
                                    <h4>Damit es wieder mit Volldampf voraus gehen kann</h4>
                                    <p>Die Einsatzgebiete für Dampf sind vielfältig. Sei es im Spital, der Universitätskantine, der Molkerei, der Wäscherei, der Lederverarbeitung, der Gummiherstellung, in der gesamten Lebensmittelindustrie, beim Gemüsebauer um Randen und Mais zu kochen, in der Futtermühle, der Getreidemühle oder in der Käserei. Mit unserer <b>Dampfkessel - Vermietung</b> helfen wir Ihnen schnell und kompetent bei Ausfällen, damit Sie Ihre Prozesse zügig wieder aufnehmen können. 
        </p>                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END SINGLE SERVICE -->

                    </div>
                    <!--.row-->
                </div>
                <!--/.container -->
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the **margin** you have given in your **css**

```
.single-service {
  margin:30px 25px;
}

.service-content {
  margin:65px;
}
```

Comment: what a shame. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove div's holding `col-sm-12` and `service-content` classes from your HTML page**

`col-sm-12` is having `15px` padding

and

```
.service-content {
    margin-left: 65px; /* because of this 65px your content is shifted to left, so remove this value or avoid using this class in HTML */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: what a shame. Thanks :)